TLS version used in graph API
We are connecting azure ad using rest connection(Graph API) and we needs to know What TLS version used in graph API.As TLS 1.0 & TLS 1.1 will disable soon.
we have checked in Microsoft but not able to find. please someone give us the confirmation and any proof(Article).

Microsoft will support TLS1.2 for US cloud.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/microsoft-graph-service-deprecating-tls-1-0-and-1-1-and-preparing-for-tls-1-2-in-us-gov-cloud/
Read the article and if you need a general start to begin reading from: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azuretls12/
I hope this answers your question.

You can check with SSLLabs: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=graph.microsoft.com.
They seem to support TLS 1.3 and 1.2, not 1.0 or 1.1.
